# Getting error "Connection with devtools was lost.Reconnecting now." on Browserstack

Tags: testing, devtools, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

In BrowserStack I selected IOS devices and opened the app by entering the URL and wanted to open the dev tools provided by BrowserStack and I tried changing some of the CSS properties in order but the Devtools are not behaving properly it is not reflecting the changes and gives me an error, So how can I fix this issue ?. I was testing for **iPhone 14 v16.4** in safari and Chrome browsers.

[image][image]